# Loop over a list of a directory path

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a list of directories in a file, I want to read the directory path and do something in the directory.I am using the following code and but getting an -

-bash: /...../Charged: Is a directory

```
for i in $( `awk '{print $2}' temp `) 
  do 
    echo $i
  done
```

Comment: Remove the backticks. You don't want to run the output of awk in the `$(...)`.

Comment: Use find - type d -execdir ...

Comment: @choroba output of awk is directory path, I want to do something using that directory path. How can I do that? 

@RamanSailopal As I said in the question, I have to read the path from a file, so I can't use `find -type d`

Comment: @RamanSailopal: As I said, use `$(...)` without the backquotes.